# Host not connected to my router shows up in a nmap scan

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

After scanning my local network with `nmap`, this host shows up listed as a `nmap` result but it is the only host that shows on `nmap` that is not listed as a client on my router list of connected devices.

```
❯ nmap 192.168.0.xxx -A                                                                                                                                                                

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-21 14:33 -03
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.xxx
Host is up (0.0056s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
6666/tcp open  upnp    MiniUPnP 1.6 (Linksys/Belkin WiFi range extender; SDK 4.1.2.0; UPnP 1.0; MTK 2.001)
|_irc-info: Unable to open connection
8888/tcp open  upnp    MiniUPnP 1.6 (Linksys/Belkin WiFi range extender; SDK 4.1.2.0; UPnP 1.0; MTK 2.001)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 37.47 seconds
```

What exactly about this host might be causing it to show on `nmap` in my local network if it (appears) not to be connected to my router?

Comment: *"What exactly about this host might be causing it to show on nmap in my local network if its not connected to my router?"* - maybe you ask the wrong question. You claim that this host is not connected to the router solely based on what your router is showing as connected. But what if this list does not show everything because your (unknown) router treats some devices differently or maybe because the routers idea of "connected" is different from what you assume.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I understand. But does that also means that necessarily this device should be  connected to my router in some way? Or it doesn't need to in order to show up in the nmap results for my local network?

Comment: Yes. It does. However, as the previous comment some routers don't treat IOT peripherals like printers as a device

Comment: I have to ask; do you in fact have a Range Extender on your network?

Comment: @user10216038 No I don't!